# JavaScript not recognizing array declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to check a user input against a predefined array of values to ensure that what the user entered is a valid input.

To do this, I'm using jQuery's `$.inArray()` function. It takes two arguments: the value to be checked, and the array to check it with. It returns the index of the value in the array if it is found, and -1 if it is not.

However, when I use the `$.inArray()` function, it does not seem to recognize the `genreArray` array (see code below). While it doesn't show up here, the `genreArray` variable does not have the proper syntax highlighting in the function call. In addition, it seems as if the `if` check gets carried out, as nothing (not even an error) shows up on the console.

The `if` statement syntax is working fine - I replace the code with `if (1 === 1)` and the code carried out fine.

In addition, the placement of the variable declaration does not seem to matter either. I've put it before/after every important point in the code, with no difference in results.

I've also ruled out any problems with the `genre` variable.

Thanks a lot for any help.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var genreArray = [...];

  $('.menu').click(function() {
    var genre = $('#genreName').val().split(' ').join('+');
    $('#error').text('');
    if ($.inArray(genre, genreArray) != -1) {
      $('#error').text('Sorry, this is not a valid genre.');
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: have you checked what value are you passing as genre ? You are doing a split on an empty field and joining the fields together with '+', that you give you a string concatenated with '+'. $.inArray() expects a single value, not concatenated value.

Comment: Please put give the actual values in the genre array and the html code of #genreName.

Comment: $.inArray need a value, why are you sending the text contatenated with "+"?, or why you trying with .split(' ').join('+')?

Comment: Please provide sample data and input values that are not working

Comment: Also logic seems backwards in conditional ... explain match case better (in words)

Comment: What did you do to rule out problems with the `genre` variable? I'm guessing your `genreArray` looks something like `['genre1','genre2','genre3']` - if you enter the text `'genre1 genre3'` in `#genreName`, your `genre` variable will be `'genre1+genre3'` . Even though `true === ($.inArray('genre1',['genre1','genre2','genre3']) != -1)` and `true === ($.inArray('genre3',['genre1','genre2','genre3']) != -1)`, `false === ($.inArray('genre1+genre3',['genre1','genre2','genre3']) != -1)`

Comment: Surely that's a whitelist not a blacklist? Use `== -1` to detect invalid ones, not `!= -1`.

Comment: Wow...Yes, all of you are right. It's obvious I didn't think this through clearly, nor did I debug enough before posting here, and I apologize for that.

Comment: I fixed it by correcting the logic and also delaying the concatenation until after the check. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did not post the full array because it has 1000+ elements. (sorry for the separate comments, I keep hitting enter to get a line return)